# How to get border pixels of an image in python?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have an image, using steganography I want to save the data in border pixels only.

In other words, I want to save data only in the least significant bits(LSB) of border pixels of an image.

Is there any way to get border pixels to store data( max 15 characters text) in the border pixels?
Plz, help me out...

Comment: This might be helpful - https://github.com/RobinDavid/LSB-Steganography

Comment: Border pixels... as in the first and last rows/columns of your image array? What do you find hard about it?

Comment: I think just with numpy slices you can get them in a matter of seconds....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OBTAINING BORDER PIXELS:**

Masking operations are one of many ways to obtain the border pixels of an image. The code would be as follows:

```
a= cv2.imread('cal1.jpg')
bw = 20 //width of border required
mask = np.ones(a.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
cv2.rectangle(mask, (bw,bw),(a.shape[1]-bw,a.shape[0]-bw), 0, -1)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(a, a, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow('out', output)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
```

After I get an array of ones with the same dimension as the input image, I use cv2.rectangle function to draw a rectangle of zeros. The first argument is the image you want to draw on, second argument is start (x,y) point and the third argument is the end (x,y) point. Fourth argument is the color and '-1' represents the thickness of rectangle drawn (-1 fills the rectangle). You can find the documentation for the function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle).

Now that we have our mask, you can use 'cv2.bitwise_and' (documentation) function to perform AND operation on the pixels. Basically what happens is, the pixels that are AND with '1' pixels in the mask, retain their pixel values. Pixels that are AND with '0' pixels in the mask are made 0. This way you will have the output as follows:

[image: here].

The input image was :

[image]

You have the border pixels now!

Using LSB planes to store your info is not a good idea. It makes sense when you think about it. A simple lossy compression would affect most of your hidden data. Saving your image as JPEG would result in loss of info or severe affected info. If you want to still try LSB, look into bit-plane slicing. Through bit-plane slicing, you basically obtain bit planes (from MSB to LSB) of the image. [image] (image from researchgate.net)

I have done it in Matlab and not quite sure about doing it in python. In Matlab, 
the function, 'bitget(image, 1)', returns the LSB of the image. I found a question on bit-plane slicing using python [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41635/bit-plane-slicing-in-python). Though unanswered, you might want to look into the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

To access border pixel and enter data into it.
A shape of an image is accessed by t= img.shape. It returns a tuple of the number of rows, columns, and channels.A component is RGB which 1,2,3 respectively.int(r[0]) is variable in which a value is stored.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('xyz.png')
t = img.shape
print(t)
component = 2
img.itemset((0,0,component),int(r[0]))
img.itemset((0,t[1]-1,component),int(r[1]))
img.itemset((t[0]-1,0,component),int(r[2]))
img.itemset((t[0]-1,t[1]-1,component),int(r[3]))

print(img.item(0,0,component))
print(img.item(0,t[1]-1,component))
print(img.item(t[0]-1,0,component))
print(img.item(t[0]-1,t[1]-1,component))
cv2.imwrite('output.png',img)
```